# I have installed Raspbian from latest NOOBS, but it doesn't appear to be latest Raspbian version

Tags: raspbian, noobs, raspbian-stretch

I configured a RPi B+ using the latest NOOBS found here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/, which I assumed had the latest Raspbian on it (Stretch, as of November 2017).

But after installing Raspbian and then performing `cat /etc/os-release` from an ssh session (logged in as the `pi` user) I'm seeing:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Which leads me to assume that it's Jessie, not Stretch that is installed. What is up with that? Either I'm reading the version information incorrectly or the latest NOOBS is installing Jessie not Stretch, or I'm losing my mind.

Which one is it?

Comment: I just re-installed from the same NOOBS image, and in the NOOBS OS selector, it definitely says it will install Debian Stretch... so what's the deal with `cat /etc/os-release`?

Comment: `apt-get install lsb-release` then run `lsb-release -c` or `lsb-release -d`

Answer (score 3):

The version of Debian depends on what's installed from the system's `sources.list`  It's not uncommon to have a mixed system based on `testing` and `unstable`.

The `/etc/os-release` file is optional.  However, it *should* match the installed version, but that's up to the OS vendor to configure.  The mismatch may cause some software to be installed and/or configured incorrectly.

File a [bug report with NOOBS](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/issues)